# Cheap Positive SSL worths?

Tags: security-certificate, cheap

Searching about cheap certificates, I saw that [ssls.com offers a positive SSL certificate](https://www.ssls.com/lp/3.88-ssl-offer.html) for $3.88 per year.

Is this even possible?

What is the difference to the [positive SSL certificate from Comodo](https://www.positivessl.com/) for $49?

What is the catch?

Comment: Hi. Are you actually asking or just promoting the website. Just asking as you only have 1 rep on stackexchange.

Comment: I am just asking, my comodo certificate expired and i need renew. Sorry, i do a mistake and log with facebook. (My stackoverflow account have 5 rep hahahaha)

Comment: np mate:) Maybe there is a way to merge accounts, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: PS: the price is quite low, but it's still only a single year. Just try to buy it and see, it's only 4$ :)

Comment: Sorry but requesting and comparing services, software and products is considered offtopic on pro webmasters.

Comment: Hi bybe, comparing SSL and other services that are critical to information security is offtopic?

Please unhold my question, @Marek Andreansky is taking all my doubts.

If you look at comments we also are talking about SEO and external links.

Seems to be unfair what you're doing

Comment: Just keep in mind that there are cheap certificates and often you get what you pay for. Of course this does not include a quality issuer offering an incentive. Just make sure the reputation of this company is good. I would not know specifically. I just like to warn people that often when searching for cheap services, they get more than they bargain for. We don't want that to happen to you of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look shows that the reduced price is only available when you buy the certificate for 1 year. Each additional year is priced fully, which mean's it's probably just a quick sale to get people singed up (with a loss?) and then get money when the extend the subscription.

It's also problematic to switch back to non-ssl from a SEO perspective - you would have to redirect all new https pages back to their http counterparts. This means that once you buy the certificate you will probably keep subscribed to keep your links up.

Comment: In my case i just want the certificate to checkout session, i don't will do it on entire shop. And using OpenCart this change is automatically.
Since you approach this issue i was wondering about active the ssl in all pages, if i do the redirect by htaccess I will loose something about my SEO? 
I mean, i will loose external links appointed to: shop.example.com (without https) even if my https change was done by htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have two urls (http and https) of the same content then it is technically duplicate content - you should really 301 redirect from one to the other to not loose any seo