# Duplicated content www on subdomain and SSL

Tags: seo, google, redirects, 301-redirect, https

I have a eCommerce based on OpenCart, but I was wondering about change my domain name for SEO purposes.

For me the critical thing about my changes are the imminent possibility of domain change, I'm freaking about damage my SEO and Google search position.
Please take this into your answer. I really need help to do not make a mistake.

The actual name put me on first page and 3 or 4 position. The new name have the exactly keyword most searched by visitors and probably i will get the first place.

As my SSL was expired I installed new one and the user @MarekAndreansky give me a hint (on my last question [Cheap Positive SSL worths?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72299/cheap-positive-ssl-worths)):
I need redirect by 301 the www to take off the duplicate content.

Today I use: `shop.example.com` (subdomain) and appears on Google like that but it's still accessible by `www.shop.example.com`

That is the first change I need do, the next is about my SSL. I need that all access by `http://shop.example.com` redirect to `https://shop.example.com`.

Things to do:

- How to do correctly that redirect in *.htaccess* and take off the duplicate content? I have found the *.htaccess* code change to DOMAINS name (not subdomain).
- How to do correctly redirect all users that access `shop.example.com` by http to `https://shop.example.com`?

I want do it to spend more confidence, but if this can damage my ranking on Google I prefer forget it.

And about the domain name change in next 10 days I will decide.

UPDATE:

My domain: loja.genesiseries.com
I will remove domain soon, so please MODS don't remove please!

My htaccess

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder     it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L]
# Tentativa de prevenir erro headers sent
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^loja\.genesiseries\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following         settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible     register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be     overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are     getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product     options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

<FilesMatch ^config.php$>
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
## INCREASE PAGE SPEED HTACCESS MODIFICATION ##
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript     application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifModule>
## END INCREASE PAGE SPEED HTACCESS MODIFICATION ##
```

[UPDATE]

Now added to htaccess:

```
# this redirects example.com and www.example.com to https - thanks closetnoc @webmasters-   stackexange
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loja\.genesiseries\.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loja\.genesiseries\.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Still give error 500, as you said i add the dot and cross bar
Something still wrong? There may be conflict with other rules?

[UPDATE 2] Below the apache error log

```
[Mon Nov 24 02:02:42 2014] [error] [client 58.37.14.114] /opt/php54/bin/php-cgi: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /opt/xslt/lib/libxslt.so.1)
[Mon Nov 24 02:02:42 2014] [error] [client 58.37.14.114] /opt/php54/bin/php-cgi: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /opt/xslt/lib/libxslt.so.1)
[Mon Nov 24 02:02:42 2014] [error] [client 58.37.14.114] /opt/php54/bin/php-cgi: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /opt/xslt/lib/libxslt.so.1)
[Mon Nov 24 02:03:54 2014] [alert] [client 189.25.157.94] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://loja.genesiseries.com/tablet-genesis-gt-7325
[Mon Nov 24 02:03:54 2014] [alert] [client 189.25.157.94] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://loja.genesiseries.com/tablet-genesis-gt-7325
[Mon Nov 24 02:03:59 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:03:59 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:01 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:02 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:02 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:02 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:02 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:03 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:04 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:04 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:04 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
[Mon Nov 24 02:04:04 2014] [alert] [client 177.180.245.74] /home/genesise/public_html/loja/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

What you suggest now?
I think that less times we use redirect is the best way, how optimize this htaccess?
Some redirects above was to assign a friendly URL

UPDATE 3

New HTACCESS

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L]
# Tentativa de prevenir erro headers sent
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^loja\.genesiseries\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# this redirects example.com and www.example.com to https - thanks closetnoc @webmasters-   stackexange
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loja\.genesiseries\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loja\.genesiseries\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loja\.genesiseries\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Still with the problem with friendly URL, i'm feeling that we are so close :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked quite a few questions and I suspect you know most of the answers already. So to clear up some confusion, I will address the subject of changing the domain name since this sounds like the *new* question. If you need more, please let us know.

Keywords in domain names mean almost nothing anymore and exact matches rarely happen as a result. That was a mistake that Google quickly realized and reverted after only a fairly short period of time. It took about 2 years. What can I say, Google is a slow learner. It polluted the search pool with bad matches just because the domain name matched the search. It was a concept that failed miserably. I could have told them that had they asked. It was a no-brainer that domain monetizers would buy domain names for $1 or just use domain tasting and spam the snot out of the search engines. Even a blind man could see that one coming.

I would not change domain names expecting better search results. In fact, you will actually lose by changing domain names. You lose all the value you have made over the lifetime of your current domain name when you change. Yes- you can do 301 redirects and recapture some/most of the value, but that old domain name must remain with a 301 redirect for that to happen. Somewhere along the line you will want to drop the old domain and you will find that you have relied upon the 301 redirect as a crutch and had not built as much value in your new domain as you should have. Plus too many redirects, and Google may not follow.

Generally speaking, unless there is a critical reason to change domain names, it is a horrible idea to do so.

There is no such thing as changing domain names for SEO purposes. Build value in the domain name you have now which seems to be working well. My grandfather always said, "If ain't broke, don't fix it!" He said a few other things, but they don't allow them on this site.

[Update]

I think this will do what you want... of course change the example.com with your domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The firs line checks to see if the request is *not* already HTTPS, the next two capture all requests, the last line redirects to HTTPS. Of course if the rewrite engine is not turned on in the configuration, then the very first line is required to enable redirects.

Okay. I just looked at your .htaccess file. You can put the lines almost anywhere, but for the sake of continuity, I would put it under:

```
# Tentativa de prevenir erro headers sent
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^loja\.genesiseries\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

... since it follows the same vein. You do not need to put in *RewriteEngine On* since you are already doing redirects- obviously it is on. As well, just for future reference, you can add a comment starting with a # like this:

```
# this redirects example.com and www.example.com to https://example.com
```

... to refresh your memory when you have to look at it again.

For what it is worth, the Apache documentation is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html It will make you go cross-eyed, but eventually you will begin to understand it and find it really is not that hard. The next thing you want to know about is regular expressions and there are good links for that on the same page.

Comment: So it's not cool redirect the https to http, www. to without www. and redirect domain? as this way it will be 3 redirect, google may not follow?

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I know there is a limit, but I do not know what the limit is. It may work just fine, but I am a firm believer in using as few redirects as possible simply because it can cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: Do you know the best way to redirect by htaccess www to non-www and http to https? I don't know anything about redirect rules :\

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I updated the answer. I think this is correct code for you. Try it and see what you get.

Comment: My htaccess have so many things I am lost, how to add the new rewriterule? can you please see my question again? I updated! I am afraid to edit and make a mistake

Comment: I got a error: 500 internal.
I tried use: 

# this redirects example.com and www.example.com to https - thanks closetnoc @webmasters-stackexange
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loja.genesiseries\.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loja.genesiseries\.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://loja.genesiseries.com/$1 [R=301,L]

where I went wrong?

Comment: @IslenoIturiel Okay. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loja.genesiseries\.com$ should have ^www\.loja\.genesiseries\.com$- you are missing a \ [slash] which escapes the . [dot] which means something in regular expressions. Try this change.

Comment: Updated question again, sorry, something still wrong :(

Comment: @IslenoIturiel Is there anything in the Apache error log? There may be a collision with another line- but let's check the log for clues first. It is possible to move it just after the *RewriteBase /* and modify the line *RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L]* to https instead of http.

Comment: Updated question with error log and details, thanks for all

Comment: @IslenoIturiel It is likely because I put a space in *[NC, OR]* which should be *[NC,OR]*. Sorry. Let's try that!

Comment: My page results in a loop redirect, it's probably the repeated redirect. As you can see the: RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L] the domain already appear redirected here, I really don't sure about but it's not what causing the error?

Comment: @IslenoIturiel You can always try commenting out the line *RewriteRule ^index\.php$ loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L]* with a # to see.

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I also noticed that the line in question is still http instead of https. You can try that change too to see what happens.

Comment: Well, after comment, your code worked but i'm still able to acess www.loja.genesiseries.com and still doesn't redirecting to https://

Comment: Changing the line: RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L] to HTTPS doesn't do any effect

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I noticed that *RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]* has *[NC,OR]* when it should be [NC]. It is a small error, but I don't think that is the problem here. You will still want to make this change. Meanwhile, I am looking to see what else.

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I updated the code in the answer. This might do the trick!

Comment: I already removed the ,OR but as you said the problem continues (still accessible www. and still http). I really appreciate your help

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I put new code in the answer. I am thinking this might work.

Comment: Wow, it work! we just got a little problem: 1- Now the https really appear instantly when we acess by http. 2- Now if i put www. instantly redirect to without www. 3- SOMETHING GONE WRONG AND BROKEN MY FRIENDLY URL :(

A example product: tablet genesis gt-7240 appear as loja.genesiseries.com/tablet-genesis-gt-7240 but when click it go to: https://loja.genesiseries.com/index.php?_route_=tablet-genesis-gt-7240 probably some conflict in rules but where?

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I think it has to do with the line we commented out *RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L]* Can we uncomment it and make sure it has https?

Comment: I added a new edit and post the new HTACCESS, but it still with the problem even uncommented this rule. By the way if i comment the RewriteRule ^index\.php$ loja.genesiseries.com? [R=301,L] your code stop working and it's like that we don't do any change, the www. still can be accessible and doesn't redirect to https

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I think if we move the new code just under *RewriteBase /* so that it gets executed first that might work.

Comment: Moved to under RewriteBase / and doesn't make any effect :( But i discover that: When we acess the shop, if i select a product appear: loja.genesiseries.com/tablet-genesis-gt-7240 for example, with friendly URL but when i access it change to: https://loja.genesiseries.com/index.php?_route_=tablet-genesis-gt-7240 but, if i try to access: loja.genesiseries.com/tablet-genesis-gt-7240 directly from browser it works! Is even possible that the problem wasn't in htaccess?

Comment: @Isleno Ituriel I am not sure. Moving to HTTPS can be tricky sometimes. I am not sure what software you are using for your site, but there might be some clues for set-up in the documentation such as a setting somewhere. Meanwhile, I will see what I can come up with. You are right. We are close!

Comment: @IslenoIturiel You might want to empty your browser cache. I went to tables and click on your 7240 link and I got what I think you are expecting.

Comment: Oh, i get it! edit comment doesn't generate a flag but i saw your comment. Well i have good news: I don't know why but it worked now! All working great except the admin panel :\ take a look: https://loja.genesiseries.com/admin/ have other type of redirect? a lot time ago someone changed my htaccess to permanent https just a little code and this kind of error don't happened. Have some way to do it?

Comment: Yes, i got the same of you but just after upload again the .htaccess (even that i not changed anything!)

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I got to your admin page okay. I am not sure what you are experiencing.

Comment: The admin page secured by https deactivated all "unsecure" resources (links and images). If you use google chrome you will be able to see it, after you mention that seem normal page I tested in internet explorer and get a the same unsecured resources page, but if i click to show all content the page appear normal, when try to login in admin i get the error again.

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I cannot log in. I enter the user name, password, then hit return and nothing. I assume that there is a button I am not seeing. Can you capture the error via text or screen shot?

Comment: Have sure, all for you. First image: http://s8.postimg.org/42r547a2t/admin_problem.jpg and http://s16.postimg.org/5vugogunp/admin_problem2.jpg

Comment: @IslenoIturiel I see the problem is in the open cart installation. I do not know anything about open cart. Sorry. Let's do what Dan says and open a new question. I see some answers on the web for you.

Comment: I think the problem is in somewhere on https a long time ago someone modified my htaccess and i was able to access the admin page and it was working pretty. I will open another question because is more fair if i give you other correct answer, after soooooo many comments

Comment: @IslenoIturiel Okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18968/discussion-between-isleno-ituriel-and-closetnoc).