# htaccess www to non-www and non-SSL to SSL

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, https, http

I want to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS as well as redirect all www requests to non-www.

The reason for this is that I want SSL to be forced and I am currently unable to support SSL on my www subdomain.

This solution needs to support all combinations of HTTP, HTTPS, www and non-www.
The best solutions I have found so far supports all combinations except www and HTTPS at the same time.

Thank you for your time. :)

EDIT: Just to explicitly state it once again, to avoid any more incorrect duplication suggestion:
I want to redirect **from www to non-www** not the other way around.
I also want to force SSL at the same time.

Comment: "except www and HTTPS at the same time" - You won't be able to redirect `www` _and_ HTTPS if your certificate does not support this. That's the point of the SSL cert - it kicks in _before_ everything else, so you'll get the cert warning before your site is able to deal with the request.

Comment: So what if I redirect to non-www and THEN to SSL?
And in some way exclude www from even using the certificate in the first place?

Comment: I have an example of what you are asking for here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72317/duplicated-content-www-on-subdomain-and-ssl/72319#72319

Comment: Although the problem you state is if somebody navigates to `https://www.example.com` - unless your cert supports the `www` subdomain then you can't redirect anything in this instance. Otherwise you can use the existing solutions.